# How do I correctly use states?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form that has a field with conditional validation. I mean if a certain radio button is checked, then the field need to be required.
Please find below a code snippet of how I tried to solve it. Unfortunately, when I run this code, the field disappears, and when I comment out this logic, the field appears again.

I implemented the code from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['the_field'] = [
    '#states' => [
      // Only make the field 'the_field' as required when the 'field_of_type_radio' value is equal to '1'.
      'required' => [
        ':input[name="field_of_type_radio"]' => ['value' => '1'],
      ],
    ],
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // If your field is link field
  $form['the_field']['widget'][0]['uri']['#states'] = [
    // Only make the field 'the_field' as required when the 'field_of_type_radio' value is equal to '1'.
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="field_of_type_radio"]' => ['value' => '1'],
    ],
  ];
  // If your field is text field
  $form['the_field']['#states'] = [
    // Only make the field 'the_field' as required when the 'field_of_type_radio' value is equal to '1'.
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="field_of_type_radio"]' => ['value' => '1'],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Hey hey, could you please add some more explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are highly discouraged.